# Generating Image from binary encoded string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, typed-arrays

I trying to get an image from an API which is returning like below

Here is the response im getting:
[image: reponse]

I don't know which format it is but i want to display it as an image.I thought i was some binary encoded string so i tried converting it to Base64 by using

```
window.btoa(data)

 <img ng-src="{{data:image/png;base64, <base64string>}}"></img>
```

But i'm not able to display image.

I found some answers by searching in google, but it was not clear. Can any one help me in this please.

Comment: Why do you think it is image? It can be anything. Zipped image, encoded text, just random bytes.

Comment: In the response headers i can see Content-Type as image/png,

Comment: I can able to see the response as image while testing with Postman

Comment: The response is a binary representation of a PNG file. Just read it as ArrayBuffer (which you convert to a blob) or directly as Blob, create an Object-URL for it and set that as image src instead. You can alternatively base-64 encode the response but that is just overhead and unnecessary here. Or depending on how you read it, instead of getting it as binary data via XHR (if that's the case) just set the URL you use with XHR to directly as src for the image.

Comment: window.btoa(data) won't give the correct base-64 format you need as it deals with strings.

Comment: Hi @K3N Thank you for your answer. How can i enable download form that URL